# Can't get value from array in BAT file

Tags: arrays, batch-file, variables

I have this code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem FILL ARRAY
set n=0
for %%a in (A B C) do (
   set fname[!n!]=%%a
   set /A n+=1
)

rem FIRST OUTPUT
for /L %%i in (0,1,2) do (
   echo !fname[%%i]!
)
echo/

rem SECOND OUTPUT
echo !fname[0]!
echo !fname[1]!
echo !fname[2]!
echo/

rem THIRD OUTPUT DOESN'T WORK
set n=0
for %%a in (A B C) do (
   echo !fname[!n!]!
   set /A n+=1
)
```

And get:

```
A
B
C

A
B
C

n
n
n
```

For some reasons I need output in **third** style and expect the same output like in first and second case but I can't understand what's wrong with it.

**Update.**
Thank you, folks. I guess I've confused you a little but really I need to use this output in variable, so I've found this working solution, maybe it'll help somebody else:

```
rem THIRD OUTPUT WORKS
set n=0
for %%a in (A B C) do (
   for /f "tokens=2* delims==" %%x in ('set fname[!n!]') do (
   <... using %%x...>
   )
   set /A n+=1
)
rem %%x contains output now and can be used anywhere
```

Comment: Please show me an actual example of the copy script, I know it is similar to this, but I need to see how you are determining meta variable `%%a` in order to give you a working script. I am getting idea you're overcomplicating something.

Comment: Thank you a lot. Could you appraise my solution if you have one more minute?)) It works but I think it can be more elegant.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990

Comment: Can't see what's wrong? Consider `echo !fname[!n!]!`. This would be evaluated as `echo the currentvalue of "fname["      n       the currentvalue of "]"`  Neither variable `fname[` nor `]` is defined, hence replaced by *nothing*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need another layer of parsing.

```
call echo %%fname[!n!]%%
```

or

```
for %%n in (!n!) do echo !fname[%%n]!
```

cures your third case.

Incorporated into your script:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem FILL ARRAY
set n=0
for %%a in (A B C) do (
   set fname[!n!]=%%a
   set /A n+=1
)

rem skip first and second output

rem THIRD OUTPUT WORKS
set n=0
for %%a in (D E F) do (
  call echo Copy "%%a" "%%fname[!n!]%%"
  for %%n in (!n!) do ECHO cOpy "%%a" "!fname[%%n]!"
  for /f "tokens=1* delims==" %%x in ('set fname[!n!]') do echo coPy "%%a" "%%y"
  set /A n+=1
)
```

of course use *just one* of the three lines (and don't forget to remove the `ECHO` after troubleshooting)

Comment: Thank you a lot. Could you appraise my solution if you have one more minute?)) It works but I think it can be more elegant.

Comment: works fine (I included it into my answer and made it safer). Perfectly valid approach (as they say: there is more than one way to skin the cat)